# Do developers need to be administrators on their machine?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, administrator

Do developers in .Net needs to be administrators on their machine or can we set a kind of permission and role?

Comment: Asking other devs whether you should give devs admin access is a bit biased. "When someone asks you if you're a god, you say YES!"

Comment: Belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com (also, I'm pretty sure this has been asked several times)

Comment: Wrong question.  It should read "Does it make sense for bean counters to restrict programmers from configuring their own machine".  No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends.  If you need to be able to create and install Windows Services, for example, then yes - they'll need proper permissions for doing that.  While you can potentially develop without it, you won't be able to properly test the service without being able to install and uninstall it.

If you're doing "normal" development, then it's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Depends. Not necessary, but it's nice to have.

Answer (score 3):

You do need higher privileges to run Web Apps in IIS instead of Cassini.  Since I prefer to test using the correct deployment environment, I do run VS 2010 in the context of an Admin.

Here is the error you will get if you are only a user:

> The Web Application Project foo is
>   configured to use IIS. To access local
>   IIS Web sites, you must run Visual
>   Studio in the context of an
>   administrator account.

Comment: And that's why IIS express is coming.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking the wrong question, you should be asking:

> Will a good developer work for an
>   employer that does not give him/her
>   admin rights on their PC?

What someone “needs” and what they expect are often not the same thing, after all you don’t need to allow a developer to drink coffee in work hours, but if you don’t…

Answer (score 2):

**Absolutely.**

I know this sounds like an overstatement, however I can't recall how many times my work was unproductive due to lack of required privileges. It's stupid if you can't install TortoiseSVN on your own or set up a windows service.

If you don't trust your developers with their toolset, why bother hiring them?

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes find it very hard to work if I don't have administrator permissions on my machine. It is more often than not that I need to install some programs to help my on my regular work or do some other administration tasks on the machine to complete something and it is really annoying and time consuming to call the IO department for such little things.